# CSS styling is not reflecting

Tags: html, css, styles, e-commerce

I'm trying to build an ecommerce website by watching a YouTube video. I am stuck at apply CSS style to some classes. I have given my full html CSS code below.Right now i am trying to style "sm- banner"element.in that css element i put two images as banner. CSS styling is not applying to its content.the two banner images are showing together there is no space in between and flex styling is not working.Please check the css element "sm-banner .banner-box{" to know the actual error

```css
@import url('https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Roboto+Slab&family=Spartan:wght@100;200;300;400;500;600;700;800;900&display=swap');

*{
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    font-family: 'Spartan' sans-serif;
}

h1{
    font-size: 50PX;
    line-height: 64px;
    color: #222;

}

h2{
    font-size: 46PX;
    line-height: 54px;
    color: #222;

}

h4{
    font-size: 20PX;
    color: #222;

}

h6{
    font-weight: 700;
    font-size: 12px
}



p{
    font-size: 16PX;
    color: #465b52;
    margin: 15px 0 20px 0;

}

.section-p1{
    padding: 40px 80px;

}

.section-p1{
    margin: 40px 0;

}

section-m1{
    margin: 40px 0;
}

button.normal{
    font-size: 14px;
    font-weight: 600;
    padding: 15px 30px;
    color: #000;
    background-color: #fff;
    border-radius: 4px;
    cursor: pointer;
    border: none;
    outline: none;
    transition: 0.2s;
    width: 250px;
    margin: auto;
    
}


body{
    width: 100%;
}




/*header start*/

#header{

    display: flex;
    justify-content: space-between ;
    align-items: center;
    padding: 20px 80px;
    background-color: #e3e6f3;
    box-shadow: 0px 5px 15p rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.06);
    z-index: 999;
    position: sticky;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;

}

#navbar{
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: center;
}

#navbar li{
    list-style: none;
    padding: 0 20px;
    position: relative;
}

#navbar li a{
    text-decoration: none;
    font-size: 16px;
    font-weight: 600;
    color: #1a1a1a;
    transition: 0.3s ease;
}

#navbar li a:hover,
#navbar li a.active{
    color: #088178;
}

#navbar li a.active::after,
#navbar li a:hover::after{
    content: "";
    width: 30%;
    height: 2px;
    background: #088178;
    position: absolute;
    bottom: -4px;
    left: 20px;
}

#hero{
    background-image: url("img/hero4.png");
    height: 90vh;
    width: 100%;
    background-position: top 25 right 0;
    background-size: cover;
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
    align-items: flex-start;
    justify-content: center;
}

#hero h4{
    padding-bottom: 15px;

}

#hero h1{
    color: #088178;
}

#hero button{

    background-image: url(img/button.png);
    background-color: transparent;
    color: #088178;
    border:0;
    padding: 14px 80px 14px  65px;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    cursor: pointer;
    font-weight: 700;
    font-size: 15px;
}

#feature{
    display: flex;
    align-items: center;
    justify-content: space-between;
    flex-wrap: wrap;
}

#feature .fe-box{
    width: 180px;
    text-align: center;
    padding: 25px 15px;
    box-shadow: 20px 20px 34px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.03);
    border: 1px solid #cce7d0;
    border-radius: 4px;
    margin: 15px 0;
}

#feature .fe-box:hover{
    box-shadow: 10px 10px 34px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.03);
}

#feature .fe-box h6{
    display: inline-block;
    padding: 9px 8px 6px 8px;
    line-height: 1;
    border-radius: 4px;
    color: #088178;
    background-color: #fddde4;
}

#feature .fe-box img{
        width: 100%;
        margin-bottom: 10px;

    



}

#product1{
    text-align: center;
}

#product1 .pro-container{
    display: flex;
    justify-content: space-between;
    padding-top: 20px;
    flex-wrap: wrap;
}

#product1 .pro{
    width: 23%;
    min-width: 250px;
    padding: 10px 12px;
    border: 1px solid #cce7d0;
    border-radius: 25px;
    cursor: pointer;
    box-shadow: 20px 20px 30px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.02);
    margin: 15px 0;
    position: relative;
}


#product1 .pro img{
    width: 100%;
    border-radius: 20px;
}

#product1 .pro .des{
    text-align: start;
    padding: 10px 0;
}


#product1 .pro .des span{
    color: #606063;
    font-size: 12px;

}

#product1 .pro .des h5{
    padding-top: 7px;
    color: #1a1a1a;
    font-size: 14px;
}

#product1 .pro .des i{
    font-size: 25px;
    color: rgb(241, 183, 25);
}

#product1 .pro .cart{
    width: 40px;
    height: 40px;
    line-height: 40px;
    border-radius: 50px;
    background-color: #e3f6ea;
    font-weight: 300;
    color: #088178;
    position: absolute;
    border: 1px solid #cce7d0;
    bottom: 20px;
    right: 10px;
    
}

#banner{
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
    justify-content: center;
    text-align: center;
    background-image: url(img/banner/b2.jpg);
    width: 100%;
    height: 40vh;
    background-size: cover;
    background-position: center;

}

#banner h4{
    color: #fff;
    font-size: 25px;
    padding: 30px 0;
}

#banner h2{
    color: #fff;
    font-size: 30px;
    padding: 10px 0;
}
#banner h2 span{
    color: #ef3636;
}

#banner button:hover{
    background-color: #088178;
    color: white;
}

#sm-banner{
    display: flex;
    justify-content: space-between;
    flex-wrap: wrap;
    
}

#sm-banner .banner-box{
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: flex-start;
    background-image: url(img/banner/b17.jpg);
    min-width: 580px;
    height: 50vh;
    background-size: cover;
    background-position: center;
    

}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Ecommerce</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://pro.fontawesome.com/releases/v5.15.4/css/all.css"/>

    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
</head>
<body>
    <section id="header">
    <a href="#"><img src="img/logo.png" class="logo"></a>
    <div>
        <ul id="navbar">
            <li><a class="active" href="index.html">Home</a></l1>
            <li><a href="shop.html">Shop</a></l1>
            <li><a href="blog.html">Blog</a></l1>
            <li><a href="about.html">About</a></l1>
            <li><a href="contact.html">Contact</a></li>
            <li><a href="cart.html"><i class="fa-solid fa-cart-arrow-down"></i></a></li>
            
        </ul>
    </div>
    </section>
    <section id="hero">
        <h4>Trade-in-offer</h4>
        <h2>Super Value Deals</h2>
        <h1>On all products</h1>
        <p>Save more with coupons & upto 70%off</p>
        <button>Shop Now</button>
    </section>
    <section id="feature" class="section-p1">
        <div class="fe-box">
            <img src="img/features/f1.png">
            <h6>Free Shipping</h6>
        </div>

        <div class="fe-box">
            <img src="img/features/f2.png">
            <h6>Online Order</h6>
        </div>

        <div class="fe-box">
            <img src="img/features/f3.png">
            <h6>Save Money</h6>
        </div>

        <div class="fe-box">
            <img src="img/features/f4.png">
            <h6>Promotions</h6>
        </div>

        <div class="fe-box">
            <img src="img/features/f5.png">
            <h6>Happy Sell</h6>
        </div>

        <div class="fe-box">
            <img src="img/features/f6.png">
            <h6>Support</h6>
        </div>
    </section>

    <section id="product1" class="section-p1">
        <h2>Featured Products</h2>
        <p>Summer Collections</p>
        <div class="pro-container">
            <div class="pro">
                <img src="img/products/f1.jpg">
                <div class="des">
                    <span>adidas</span>
                    <h5>Cartoon Astronaut Tshirt</h5>
                    <div class="star">
                        <i class="fas fa-star"></i>
                        <i class="fas fa-star"></i>
                        <i class="fas fa-star"></i>
                        <i class="fas fa-star"></i>
                        <i class="fas fa-star"></i>
                    </div>
                    <h4>$78</h4>
                </div>
                <a href="#"><i class="fal fa-shopping-cart cart"></i></a>
            </div>
            <div class="pro">
                <img src="img/products/f2.jpg">
                <div class="des">
                    <span>adidas</span>
                    <h5>Cartoon Astronaut Tshirt</h5>
                    <div class="star">
                        <i class="fas fa-star"></i>
                        <i class="fas fa-star"></i>
                        <i class="fas fa-star"></i>
                        <i class="fas fa-star"></i>
                        <i class="fas fa-star"></i>
                    </div>
                    <h4>$78</h4>
                </div>
                <a href="#"><i class="fal fa-shopping-cart cart"></i></a>
            </div>
            <div class="pro">
                <img src="img/products/f3.jpg">
                <div class="des">
                    <span>adidas</span>
                    <h5>Cartoon Astronaut Tshirt</h5>
                    <div class="star">
                        <i class="fas fa-star"></i>
                        <i class="fas fa-star"></i>
                        <i class="fas fa-star"></i>
                        <i class="fas fa-star"></i>
                        <i class="fas fa-star"></i>
                    </div>
                    <h4>$78</h4>
                </div>
                <a href="#"><i class="fal fa-shopping-cart cart"></i></a>
            </div>
            <div class="pro">
                <img src="img/products/f4.jpg">
                <div class="des">
                    <span>adidas</span>
                    <h5>Cartoon Astronaut Tshirt</h5>
                    <div class="star">
                        <i class="fas fa-star"></i>
                        <i class="fas fa-star"></i>
                        <i class="fas fa-star"></i>
                        <i class="fas fa-star"></i>
                        <i class="fas fa-star"></i>
                    </div>
                    <h4>$78</h4>
                </div>
                <a href="#"><i class="fal fa-shopping-cart cart"></i></a>
            </div>
            <div class="pro">
                <img src="img/products/f5.jpg">
                <div class="des">
                    <span>adidas</span>
                    <h5>Cartoon Astronaut Tshirt</h5>
                    <div class="star">
                        <i class="fas fa-star"></i>
                        <i class="fas fa-star"></i>
                        <i class="fas fa-star"></i>
                        <i class="fas fa-star"></i>
                        <i class="fas fa-star"></i>
                    </div>
                    <h4>$78</h4>
                </div>
                <a href="#"><i class="fal fa-shopping-cart cart"></i></a>
            </div>
            <div class="pro">
                <img src="img/products/f6.jpg">
                <div class="des">
                    <span>adidas</span>
                    <h5>Cartoon Astronaut Tshirt</h5>
                    <div class="star">
                        <i class="fas fa-star"></i>
                        <i class="fas fa-star"></i>
                        <i class="fas fa-star"></i>
                        <i class="fas fa-star"></i>
                        <i class="fas fa-star"></i>
                    </div>
                    <h4>$78</h4>
                </div>
                <a href="#"><i class="fal fa-shopping-cart cart"></i></a>
            </div>
            <div class="pro">
                <img src="img/products/f7.jpg">
                <div class="des">
                    <span>adidas</span>
                    <h5>Cartoon Astronaut Tshirt</h5>
                    <div class="star">
                        <i class="fas fa-star"></i>
                        <i class="fas fa-star"></i>
                        <i class="fas fa-star"></i>
                        <i class="fas fa-star"></i>
                        <i class="fas fa-star"></i>
                    </div>
                    <h4>$78</h4>
                </div>
                <a href="#"><i class="fal fa-shopping-cart cart"></i></a>
            </div>
            <div class="pro">
                <img src="img/products/f8.jpg"
                <div class="des">
                    <span>adidas</span>
                    <h5>Cartoon Astronaut Tshirt</h5>
                    <div class="star">
                        <i class="fas fa-star"></i>
                        <i class="fas fa-star"></i>
                        <i class="fas fa-star"></i>
                        <i class="fas fa-star"></i>
                        <i class="fas fa-star"></i>
                    </div>
                    <h4>$78</h4>
                </div>
                <a href="#"><i class="fal fa-shopping-cart cart"></i></a>
            </div>
        </div>
    </section>
    <section id="banner" class="section-m1">
        <h4>Best Service</h4>
        <h2>Up to <span>70% - off</span> on All T-shirts</h2>
        <button class="normal">Explore More</button>
    </section>
    <section id="product1" class="section-p1">
        <h2>New Arrivals</h2>
        <p>Summer Collection New Modern Design</p>
        <div class="pro-container">
            <div class="pro">
                <img src="img/products/n1.jpg">
                <div class="des">
                    <span>adidas</span>
                    <h5>Cartoon Astronaut Tshirt</h5>
                    <div class="star">
                        <i class="fas fa-star"></i>
                        <i class="fas fa-star"></i>
                        <i class="fas fa-star"></i>
                        <i class="fas fa-star"></i>
                        <i class="fas fa-star"></i>
                    </div>
                    <h4>$78</h4>
                </div>
                <a href="#"><i class="fal fa-shopping-cart cart"></i></a>
            </div>
            <div class="pro">
                <img src="img/products/n2.jpg">
                <div class="des">
                    <span>adidas</span>
                    <h5>Cartoon Astronaut Tshirt</h5>
                    <div class="star">
                        <i class="fas fa-star"></i>
                        <i class="fas fa-star"></i>
                        <i class="fas fa-star"></i>
                        <i class="fas fa-star"></i>
                        <i class="fas fa-star"></i>
                    </div>
                    <h4>$78</h4>
                </div>
                <a href="#"><i class="fal fa-shopping-cart cart"></i></a>
            </div>
            <div class="pro">
                <img src="img/products/n3.jpg">
                <div class="des">
                    <span>adidas</span>
                    <h5>Cartoon Astronaut Tshirt</h5>
                    <div class="star">
                        <i class="fas fa-star"></i>
                        <i class="fas fa-star"></i>
                        <i class="fas fa-star"></i>
                        <i class="fas fa-star"></i>
                        <i class="fas fa-star"></i>
                    </div>
                    <h4>$78</h4>
                </div>
                <a href="#"><i class="fal fa-shopping-cart cart"></i></a>
            </div>
            <div class="pro">
                <img src="img/products/n4.jpg">
                <div class="des">
                    <span>adidas</span>
                    <h5>Cartoon Astronaut Tshirt</h5>
                    <div class="star">
                        <i class="fas fa-star"></i>
                        <i class="fas fa-star"></i>
                        <i class="fas fa-star"></i>
                        <i class="fas fa-star"></i>
                        <i class="fas fa-star"></i>
                    </div>
                    <h4>$78</h4>
                </div>
                <a href="#"><i class="fal fa-shopping-cart cart"></i></a>
            </div>
                    <div class="pro">
                        <img src="img/products/n5.jpg">
                        <div class="des">
                            <span>adidas</span>
                            <h5>Cartoon Astronaut Tshirt</h5>
                            <div class="star">
                                <i class="fas fa-star"></i>
                                <i class="fas fa-star"></i>
                                <i class="fas fa-star"></i>
                                <i class="fas fa-star"></i>
                                <i class="fas fa-star"></i>
                            </div>
                            <h4>$78</h4>
                        </div>
                        <a href="#"><i class="fal fa-shopping-cart cart"></i></a>
                    </div>
                    <div class="pro">
                        <img src="img/products/n6.jpg">
                        <div class="des">
                            <span>adidas</span>
                            <h5>Cartoon Astronaut Tshirt</h5>
                            <div class="star">
                                <i class="fas fa-star"></i>
                                <i class="fas fa-star"></i>
                                <i class="fas fa-star"></i>
                                <i class="fas fa-star"></i>
                                <i class="fas fa-star"></i>
                            </div>
                            <h4>$78</h4>
                        </div>
                        <a href="#"><i class="fal fa-shopping-cart cart"></i></a>
                    </div>
                    <div class="pro">
                        <img src="img/products/n7.jpg">
                        <div class="des">
                            <span>adidas</span>
                            <h5>Cartoon Astronaut Tshirt</h5>
                            <div class="star">
                                <i class="fas fa-star"></i>
                                <i class="fas fa-star"></i>
                                <i class="fas fa-star"></i>
                                <i class="fas fa-star"></i>
                                <i class="fas fa-star"></i>
                            </div>
                            <h4>$78</h4>
                        </div>
                        <a href="#"><i class="fal fa-shopping-cart cart"></i></a>
                    </div>
                    <div class="pro">
                        <img src="img/products/n8.jpg">
                        <div class="des">
                            <span>adidas</span>
                            <h5>Cartoon Astronaut Tshirt</h5>
                            <div class="star">
                                <i class="fas fa-star"></i>
                                <i class="fas fa-star"></i>
                                <i class="fas fa-star"></i>
                                <i class="fas fa-star"></i>
                                <i class="fas fa-star"></i>
                            </div>
                            <h4>$78</h4>
                        </div>
                        <a href="#"><i class="fal fa-shopping-cart cart"></i></a>
                    </div>
                   
                    <section id="sm-banner" class="section-p1">
                        <div class="banner-box">
                            <h4>Crazy deals</h4>
                            <h2>buy 1 get 1 Free</h2>
                            <button>Learn More</button>
                        </div>

                    </section>
                    <script src="script.js"></script>
    
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: as a side-note, I would watch a youtube video uploaded with from an actual webstack developer. Espacially someone that knows semantic tags and their importance for screen readers (accessibility). `<section id="header">` should be just `<header>` (header is schematically not a section) or the navbar `<nav>`.

Comment: There are no images anywhere in the `sm-banner` could you explain exactly which part of the styling is not applying? Cause as far as i can tell everything in the css is applying properly unless you mean the background images which are not stylable via flexboxes

Comment: There is a comma missing between the fonts in font-family.

Comment: I am talking about the bg image named b17.jpg

Comment: Show me the template of your website

Comment: I wrote answer your

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Follow the step-by-step instructions HTML and CSS:

- You shouldn't miss a single tag and placed them correctly
- You shouldn't make typographical or orographic errors
- You should write capital and small letters where appropriate
- You shouldn't forget a single necessary symbol and shouldn't make a mistake in their placement
- You should use straight quotation marks (" "), not curly (“ ”) or herringbones (« »)
- You should close all the tags, and put a slash `/` at the end
- A CSS rule consists of a selector and a declaration block.
- The selector points to the HTML element you want to style.
- The declaration block contains one or more declarations separated by semicolons.
- Each declaration includes a CSS property name and a value, separated by a colon.
- Multiple CSS declarations are separated with semicolons, and declaration blocks are surrounded by curly braces.

CSS Rule -

[image]

If you want to check HTML good click [here](https://validator.w3.org/), CSS [here](https://jigsaw.w3.org/css-validator/validator.html.en).